# ¿Cómo llenar una tabla en HTML con un arreglo con índices asociativos PHP de manera vertical (columnas a filas)?

Tags: php, html, array

Tengo el siguiente arreglo.

```
$G8=array('EUROPA' => array("Alemania","Francia","Italia","Reino Unido"),
'ASIA' => array("Rusia","Japón"),
'AMERICA' => array ("Estados Unidos","Canada"),
'AFRICA' => array("Sudafrica"),
'OCEANIA' => array("Australia"));
```

Y lo estoy imprimiendo de esta manera

```
<table width="100%" border="1">

    <?php
    foreach($G8 as $key => $value){
    ?>
    
    <tr> 
        <th>
            <?php echo $key;?>
        </th>
            <?php 
            foreach($value as $key=>$value){
            ?>
        <td>
            <?php echo $value;?>
        </td>
            <?php
            }
            ?>
    </tr>
    
    <?php
    }
    ?>

</table>
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

¿Hay alguna forma de imprimir lo mismo pero que la primera columna sea la primera fila? ¿Y que los valores de cada arreglo se desplieguen hacia abajo?

Comment: Ten en cuenta que cada <tr> es una fila, por tanto, necesitaras uno de estos por cada nivel de la tabla, el primero conteniendo los continentes y los demás generados con código según los países

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Todo el truco está en que al recorrer la cabecera vamos guardando el valor más grande de los array hijos, con lo cual (y mediante un for) podemos crear el resto de las filas, ya que conocemos la cantidad a generar

```
<?php
$G8=array('EUROPA' => array("Alemania","Francia","Italia","Reino Unido"),
'ASIA' => array("Rusia","Japón"),
'AMERICA' => array ("Estados Unidos","Canada"),
'AFRICA' => array("Sudafrica"),
'OCEANIA' => array("Australia"));

$largo=0;
?>

<body>
    <table width="100%" border="1">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <?php foreach($G8 as $key => $value): ?>
                    <th><?php echo $key; ?></th>
                <?php $largo = count($value) > $largo ? count($value) : $largo; //guardamos el largo máximo?>
                <?php endforeach; ?>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <?php for($i=0; $i<$largo; $i++): ?>
                <tr>
                    <?php 
                    foreach($G8 as $key => $value) {
                        if($value[$i]){
                            echo "<td>".$value[$i]."</td>";
                        }
                        else{
                            echo "<td></td>";
                        }
                    }
                    ?>
                </tr>
            <?php endfor; ?>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</body>
```

Resultado:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1):

Buen día,

Ya tienes la parte que crea la tabla funcionando, lo que te hace falta es la parte que crea el arreglo de tal forma que el primer elemento de cada sub arreglo de `$G8` se combine en un arreglo, el segundo elemento de cada sub arreglo de `$G8` se combine en otro arreglo y así sucesivamente, rellenando los valores inexistentes con `NULL` para de esa forma crear un arreglo de filas.

En esta respuesta me enfoco en como generar el nuevo arreglo con la estructura que necesitas para poder crear la tabla.

```
<?php
$G8 = array(
            'EUROPA' => array("Alemania","Francia","Italia","Reino Unido"),
            'ASIA' => array("Rusia","Japón"),
            'AMERICA' => array ("Estados Unidos","Canada"),
            'AFRICA' => array("Sudafrica"),
            'OCEANIA' => array("Australia")
        );

// Opción 1, array_map y cada sub arreglo
$filas1 = array_map(null, $G8['EUROPA'], $G8['ASIA'], $G8['AMERICA'], $G8['AFRICA'], $G8['OCEANIA']);
var_dump($filas1);

// Opción 2, obtener los sub arreglos
// Utilizar array merge para rellenar con null
// call_user_func_array que utiliza array_map para mapear los arreglos
$sub_arrays = array_values($G8);
$filas2 = call_user_func_array('array_map', array_merge(array(null), $sub_arrays));
var_dump($filas2);
?>
```

En la primera opción hay que agregar cada sub arreglo a [`array_map`](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.array-map.php) para que genere el nuevo arreglo deseado donde cada sub arreglo sería una fila de tu tabla.

En la segunda opción se puede utilizar `call_user_func_array` que llamará `array_map` para crear el nuevo arreglo con los sub arreglos en el orden deseado

El resultado del código anterior es el siguiente, como se puede ver en ambos casos el resultado es el mismo:

```
array(4) {
  [0]=>
  array(5) {
    [0]=>
    string(8) "Alemania"
    [1]=>
    string(5) "Rusia"
    [2]=>
    string(14) "Estados Unidos"
    [3]=>
    string(9) "Sudafrica"
    [4]=>
    string(9) "Australia"
  }
  [1]=>
  array(5) {
    [0]=>
    string(7) "Francia"
    [1]=>
    string(6) "Japón"
    [2]=>
    string(6) "Canada"
    [3]=>
    NULL
    [4]=>
    NULL
  }
  [2]=>
  array(5) {
    [0]=>
    string(6) "Italia"
    [1]=>
    NULL
    [2]=>
    NULL
    [3]=>
    NULL
    [4]=>
    NULL
  }
  [3]=>
  array(5) {
    [0]=>
    string(11) "Reino Unido"
    [1]=>
    NULL
    [2]=>
    NULL
    [3]=>
    NULL
    [4]=>
    NULL
  }
}
array(4) {
  [0]=>
  array(5) {
    [0]=>
    string(8) "Alemania"
    [1]=>
    string(5) "Rusia"
    [2]=>
    string(14) "Estados Unidos"
    [3]=>
    string(9) "Sudafrica"
    [4]=>
    string(9) "Australia"
  }
  [1]=>
  array(5) {
    [0]=>
    string(7) "Francia"
    [1]=>
    string(6) "Japón"
    [2]=>
    string(6) "Canada"
    [3]=>
    NULL
    [4]=>
    NULL
  }
  [2]=>
  array(5) {
    [0]=>
    string(6) "Italia"
    [1]=>
    NULL
    [2]=>
    NULL
    [3]=>
    NULL
    [4]=>
    NULL
  }
  [3]=>
  array(5) {
    [0]=>
    string(11) "Reino Unido"
    [1]=>
    NULL
    [2]=>
    NULL
    [3]=>
    NULL
    [4]=>
    NULL
  }
}
```

Y ese nuevo arreglo que genera las filas se puede adaptar al código que ya tienes para generar tu tabla de la forma que deseas por lo que en lugar de utilizar `$G8` en la parte donde generas tu tabla puedes utilizar `$filas1` o `$filas2` dependiendo de la opción que elijas. Ten en cuenta que el nombr de los continentes no aparece en el nuevo arreglo así que ese lo puedes obtener directamente de tu arreglo original `$G8`.

Answer (score 1):

Espero poder darme a entender con el código:

```
<table width="100%" border="1">
    <!-- Fila de titulos (nombres continentes) -->
    <tr>
    <?php 
        $maxCountryCount = 0; //Conteo de mayor numero de paises en un continente.
        foreach($G8 as $continentName => $countryNames){ 
            echo "<th> {$continentName} </th>";

            $i = count($countryNames);
            if($i >= $maxCountryCount){
                $maxCountryCount = $i;
            }

        }
    ?>
    </tr>
    <!-- Filas de paises -->
    <?php 
        $conteo = 0;
        while ($conteo < $maxCountryCount) {
            $arrayCountriesContinent = []; //Almacena el pais que se encuentre en el index dado conteo del array de paises de cada continente
            //Por ejemplo en conteo = 1, se almacenara: ["Francia","Japon","Canada"];
            $tdTotal = ""; // String al que se le suman etiquetas <td> conteniendo los paises recopilados en arrayCountriesContinent

            foreach($G8 as $continentName => $countryNames){ 
                if(!(count($countryNames) - 1 < $conteo)){
                    array_push($arrayCountriesContinent, $countryNames[$conteo]);
                }else{
                    array_push($arrayCountriesContinent, "");
                }
                
            }
            foreach ($x as $key => $value) {
                $tdTotal .= "<td>{$value}</td>";
            }
            echo "<tr>{$tdTotal}</tr>"; //Agrega filas con los datos de tdTotal
            $y++;
        }
    ?>
</table>
```

Dando el siguiente resultado:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como mencioné en el comentario, hay que considerar que cada etiqueta `tr` es una fila, incluyendo la fila de los headers `th`; en el código lo que hice fue primero crear la primera fila con los nombres de los continentes y de una vez en ese mismo foreach obtener cual es el número más alto de países en los continentes (pensando en la posibilidad de que vayas a añadir mas paises a futuro) para luego usarlo como referencia de cuantas veces debería iterar el `while` (que es lo mismo a cuantas filas deberán crearse para los paises).

En este caso como Europa tiene el mayor número de países (4) va a iterar 4 veces por cada país donde en la primera iteración `$arrayCountriesContinent` contendra `["Alemania", "Rusia", "Estados Unidos", "Sudáfrica", "Australia"]`, y en la segunda iteración: `["Francia", "Japón", "Canadá","",""]`.

Sinceramente fue la primera solución que se me ocurrió y algo me dice que debe existir una forma más optimizada de lograr el mismo resultado, pero espero te sea de ayuda. Saludos.